# Store result of a query in variable in shell script

Tags: shell, unix

I am trying to fetch value from SQL table and then want to store in variable. I tried as below:

```
TimeStamp=`
sqlplus -s $DB<set heading off  #DB="x/x@x";
set feedback off
SELECT TO_CHAR( date_value, 'HH:MM:SS') from x_date;
exit
EOF`;
```

where `x_date` has only one column i.e. `date_value` and only one row with say date as 11-nov-2014.

What is wrong with my statement?

Comment: You appear to have lost `<EOF` from between the `<` and `set` in the second line for starters.

Comment: thanks got it...i missed  "<< EOF"

Answer (score 0):

I missed "<< EOF" before set and after $DB.